# Use batch file to conditionally replace values in csv

Tags: csv, batch-file, conditional-statements

This batch file is intended to update column 8 (Department) of a csv file based on the value in column 17 (Publisher). The batch file runs -- and produces no error messages -- but the output file is exactly the same as the input file -- column 8 is not updated. I have reviewed the answers to my previous questions, googled numerous tutorials, and researched other stackoverflow questions. Here are my questions: (1) what is the proper syntax for the if statement to check the value of column 17 and (2) what is the proper syntax for setting a variable for column 8 within a loop (for /f) command?

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem | Move Manga to Manga Department

for /f "tokens=1-17,* delims=," %%A in (file.csv) do (
    set "department=%%H"
    set "publisher=%%Q"
    if "!department!"=="3" (

        if "!publisher!"=="YEN PRESS" (

        set "%%H=1010"

        )

    )

>>file_14.csv echo %%A,%%B,%%C,%%D,%%E,%%F,%%G,%%H,%%I,%%J,%%K,%%L,%%M,%%N,%%O,%%P,%%Q,%%R

)

@echo on
```

---

```
1,"MAY090178","D ","BATMAN HUSH COMPLETE TP (C: 1-1-0)",24.99,11.2455,11.25,3,7,         ,62464962,"76194127923700111","1401223176","978140122317552499","                    ",0,"DC COMICS",000000
1,"NOV141747","F ","BLACK BUTLER GN VOL 19 (C: 1-1-0)",13.00,7.5400,7.54,3,7,         ,62464962,"","0316259403","978031625940851300","                    ",0,"YEN PRESS",127143
2,"MAY151682","F ","BLACK BUTLER GN VOL 20 (C: 1-1-0)",13.00,7.5400,15.08,3,7,         ,62464962,"","0316305014","978031630501351300","                    ",0,"YEN PRESS",127143
```

Comment: I strongly suggest that you make more of an effort with this before being so rude as to ask for help again. This is the same csv data as your earlier question, and a very similar task. Learn from the previous answer, _which you've already accepted_, and use what you've learned in formulating your own code which attempts the task you've presented. If that fails to work to satisfaction [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53972706/edit), presenting a [mcve] of the code, with before and after results and a concise summary of any error messages and fixes you've tried to fix it.

Comment: Please note also that questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. I have flagged your question as off-topic.

Comment: Sorry, don't mean to be rude. I've been using the results of my previous questions and looking at other examples which is how I've formulated the code above. While similar, each of these tasks is different than the others. I am not getting any error message -- the batch file runs but the output file is identical to the input file. Thank you for your comments -- I appreciate your time.

Comment: The questions may be different, but it looks like you're still dealing with the same data, which suggests that you have some ultimate goal for your content. If you're just trying to organize everything, there is almost certainly software that already exists for this.

Comment: You don't seem to understand what `set "%%H=1010"` does. The set command expects varname=value, so you're using the content of %%H which is read from the file and trying to set a local variable by that name.

Comment: There are three things that are really hard to get right in programming: naming things and avoiding off by one errors.

Comment: @double-beep, I think this is a typical newb question. If you're going to flag them, at least point them to [Ask] and [MCVE] first and give them some time to adapt.

Comment: @jwdonahue bingo! Please make it an answer: `set "department=1010"` and then `>>file_14.csv echo %%A,%%B,%%C,%%D,%%E,%%F,%%G,!department!,%%I,%%J,%%K,%%L,%%M,%%N,%%O,%%P,%%Q,%%R` seem to fix the problem.

Comment: Next time, simplify your problem statement. In this case, a data set with one line that would be modified and one that wouldn't is sufficient for the input example. Also post the actual results that your getting. You were very close. By the time you wrote it up and posted the input and the output data, you'd probably have realized where the problem was without any help. This is why we insist on folds reading and understanding [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Your question says you are looking at both field 17 and 18 to be "XYZ". Which field are you really wanting to look are you really wanting to look at? Ate you counting the fields starting at 0 or 1?

Comment: Hmm... meant to say 'folks', not 'folds'.

Answer (score 1):

The set command expects varname=value. You're using the content of %%H which is read from the file and trying to set a local variable by that name. Try:

```
set department=1010
```

Then:

```
>>file_14.csv echo %%A,%%B,%%C,%%D,%%E,%%F,%%G,!department!,%%I,%%J,%%K,%%L,%%M,%%N,%%O,%%P,%%Q,%%R
```

I did think I spotted an off-by-one error in there. Verify your results are actually correct. Your `tokens=1-17,*` can bite you later if more fields are added to the csv file. `tokens=1-18,*' makes more sense to me.  I don't think it matters for you if there's nothing beyond the 18th field, so you might as well future-proof your script.

In addition to the above, I would get rid of the`@echo off` and `echo on` lines or put the `@setlocal ...` statement at the top of script. You shouldn't muck around with the users  environment like that. See `help setlocal`.  You can always put the `@` symbol in front of every script command, to avoid having that particular command displayed. The problem with `@echo off` at the beginning of the script is that it is sticky. If the script fails somewhere the state of the echo flag is whatever it was last set to. This makes script with such commands in them, uncomposable.

It's easier to debug a script when each command is preceded by the `@` symbol:

```
@setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

@rem | Move Manga to Manga Department

@for /f "tokens=1-17,* delims=," %%A in (file.csv) do (
    @set "department=%%H"
    @set "publisher=%%Q"
    @if "!department!"=="3" (
        @if "!publisher!"=="XYZ" (
        @set "department=1010"
        )
    )
    >>file_14.csv @echo %%A,%%B,%%C,%%D,%%E,%%F,%%G,!department!,%%I,%%J,%%K,%%L,%%M,%%N,%%O,%%P,%%Q,%%R
)
```

This way when you are debugging, you can remove the a relevant `@` or two and not have to read through the entire spew. If the script winds up being called from another script, you won't wind up with the incomprehensible spew results if the an `echo` `off/on` is missed as a result of script failure.

Comment: I had to delete the @ in front of the echo command to get it to run. However, it did not change any of the departments to 1010 -- they are all still 3. Thanks for the information regarding debugging. I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: If you included my @rem statement, it probably would have failed due to the redirect at the end.